# Adding offset to Chart.js Bubble Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

After going through all of the Chart.js documentation, it seems like there isn't a way to add any kind of offset to a bubble chart on either the left or right side of the chart.

Any min/max X value is just automatically placed at the extremes of the chart and short of adding superfluous data, it seems like there isn't a great option. Therefor, if a point is large enough (or just not tiny), it overlaps on the left axis or goes off the canvas on the right.

Is there not a way to control this?

[View of offending chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwdjT.png)

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using chart.js v2.7.2